# C++ beginners and homework

Tags: feature-request, homework

I find too many of the questions, at least in C++, are homework or just very simple.

I wish these could be somehow separated from questions that require an expert.

How about Stack Overflow creating a "C++ homework" tag and/or a "C++ beginner" tag?

Comment: There isn't anything special about "homework" or "beginner" questions, why *should* they be handled differently? I've seen a lot of these questions with more thought put into them than some of the more "expert" questions.

Comment: Bad questions are bad questions, no matter what level they're asked at. There are indeed lots of bad questions in the C++ tag, but they can't all be distinguished by being homework questions. There are plenty of *good* homework questions that need real answers by knowledgeable experts, and it can be good practice for experts to explain complicated concepts to relative newbies. It certainly isn't always easy, but it's an important skill, as long as you don't let elitism take hold.

Comment: Wait - is C++ still being taught?

Comment: Why would C++ *not* be taught, @Glorfindel?

Comment: @CodyGray - because s/he has seen the results of such attempts?  I'm sure that people are being paid to teach C++, and turn up for work and talk to students, but it there any point?   Half the students in the theatre are downloading homework answers from the web and posting them to SO to get them peronalized and working, the other half are copying from the first half, typing in the code and posting it to SO without even bothering to compile it.

Comment: I am not quite that cynical, @Martin. But if I were, what would be the difference between C++ and any other language? Or, for that matter, any subject? Cheaters are gonna cheat.

Comment: Although I don't agree with your suggestion, it is still a valid suggestion and doesn't deserve -19 points. Jesus. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We all want to find complex questions to answer more than we want to explain *again* what `$` is undefined means, but add these tags as a solution?

Please no. That would just encourage them.

Their questions should stand alone at the very least, if that isn't the case they need to be closed not marked as "homework".

Comment: Beginner-level questions with obvious answers are >90% likely to have been asked before, so just close them as duplicates. That way, everybody wins.

Comment: Regular SO contributors lose.  They have to find the dups and link them.  The 'beginners' win - they get an answer without expending any effort on searching the web or SO, after all, why should they waste time on that when there is an army of drones willing to do it for them?

Comment: @MartinJames Worse still, closing as a duplicate means the rep whores don't get to earn rep posting the 1001st answer to the frequently asked question that they can write in 30 seconds without really thinking and get lots of rep for.  So it's literally *only* the help vampires that win.

Comment: @Servy - If there were more close reasons that only applied to users with <100 reputation, do you think that would allow that type of question to be closed faster? Perhaps it could even be something which was not a duplicate choice if the quality was below a certain standard.